# How can I display relevant data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table SHIPPING, which looks like this:

| INVOICE | DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_ID | ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_ID | DATE_OF_TRANSFER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123-123 | 1 | 3 | 02.05.2022 |
| 123-432 | 8 | 4 | 12.06.2022 |

And I have AIRPORT table whick looks like this:

| AIRPORT_ID | CODE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LEJ | Leipzig |
| 2 | ISL | ISTANBUL |
| 3 | DXB | Dubai |
| 4 | VIE | Vienna |
| 8 | GLA | Glasgow |

I need to display airport CODE instead of AIRPORT_ID in SHIPPING table. So my table should look like this:

| INVOICE | DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_ID | ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_ID | DATE_OF_TRANSFER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123-123 | LEJ | DXB | 02.05.2022 |
| 123-432 | GLA | VIE | 12.06.2022 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add wha you already tried. Also, it's a bit confusing that your columns are named DEPARTURE/ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_ID but show the DEPARTURE/ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_CODE

Comment: Join to AIRPORT twice with a different alias

Answer (score 0):

As @KoenLostrie wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371818/how-can-i-display-relevant-data#comment127853180_72371818)

> Join to AIRPORT twice with a different alias

```sql
select S.INVOICE
      ,D.CODE
      ,A.CODE
      ,S.DATE_OF_TRANSFER
  from SHIPPING S
  join AIRPORT D
    on S.DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_ID = D.AIRPORT_ID
  join AIRPORT A
    on S.ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_ID = A.AIRPORT_ID
```

Using the sample data from your question, above query returns the following:

| INVOICE | CODE | CODE | DATE_OF_TRANSFER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123-123 | LEJ | DXB | 02-MAY-22 |
| 123-432 | GLA | VIE | 12-JUN-22 |

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1a60cf1d06fb93bb023cbe69c51a9a83).